# R add a row number column to dataframe and handle the case that dataframe is empty

Tags: r

I have a dataframe df that I want to add a column to called row_num that represents the index of the row. This was my initial solution:

```
 df$row_num<-seq(1:nrow(df))
```

However, it doesn't work in the case that df is empty as I get the error:

```
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, row_num, value = 1:2) : 
  replacement has 2 rows, data has 0
```

One solution I have found is using row_number() from dplyr but this seems to slow down my code quite a bit so I was looking for a simpler solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two problems here:

1. `1:nrow(df)` will always return something, even if `nrow(df)` is 0. Try it!

   ```r
   1:0
   # [1] 1 0
   ```

   This is because `1:0` is seen as a reverse sequence, so it counts down.
2. `seq(1:nrow(df))` is redundant. Fortunately, this isn't breaking your code, it's just sequencing along it, but it's not helping.

   ```r
   seq(1:9)
   # [1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
   seq(1:0)
   # [1] 1 2
   ```

One fix is to just use `seq_len(nrow(df))`, where `seq_len(0)` (for a 0-row frame) will return the length vector you need (i.e., length 0). (In general, I tend to recommend `seq_len(..)` any time unsupervised code is meant to iterate a programmatic number of times. Another "safe" function is `seq_along(..)`, as it will also do nothing if its input is length 0, but it isn't useful in this case.)